# how can i find the average of the observation?

Tags: java, observer-pattern

i'm really struggling with this class that generates a random number and update the observer's class. how can i find the average of all these random numbers generated? (observations_avg) and pass them to the observers

class A

```
public abstract class A implements Observer {
     public abstract String disp();
     public abstract void update(Observable subject, Object o);
}
```

class B

```
public class B extends A {

    public double limit;
    public B(double limit) {
         this.limit = limit;
    }
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
         if (observations_avg >= limit) {
              System.out.println(disp());
         }
    }
    public String disp() {  
    // observations_avg = sum of all observation, and divide it by the    quantity of them
         String d = "WARNING avg exceeded limit: " + observations_avg;
         return d;
    }
}
```

class C

```
public class C extends A {

    Avg avg = new Avg(10);
    public void update(Observable subject, Object o) {
        System.out.println(disp());
    }
    public String disp() { 
        String d = "avg is " observations_avg+ ; // i want to display the average of all the random numbers
        return d;
    }
}
```

generates the random number and update the observers class Avg

```
public class Avg extends Observable {

    private int seed;
    Random random = new Random();
    public Avg(int seed) {
        this.seed = seed;
        random.setSeed(this.seed);
    }
    public double getRandom() {
        double r = random.nextDouble()*10;
        return r;
    }
    public void read() {
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers();
    }
}
```

the main

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Avg avg = new Avg(10);
        // create observers and add them
        B B_obj = new B(8);
        C C_obj = new C();
        avg.addObserver(B_obj);
        avg.addObserver(C_obj);

        try {
            while (true) {
                avg.read();
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a method like getAverage() in the Avg object, and then retrieve the value while observing avg:

```
public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
    Avg avg = (Avg) o; 
    double observations_avg = avg.getAverage();
    if (observations_avg >= limit) {
          System.out.println(disp());
     }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much. can you explain how to calculate getAverage? this is what i'm stuck on.